# Read the SQL file and Replace from the WHERE clause in the sql file till end of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a SQL file that has a query as below. Once I read the file and based on conditions I check I want to remove from the where clause till the end of the query ..
 The Reason I want to do is if it is full load then I don't need where clause. Any help with this ??

```
select col1,
       col2 
from table 
where a >= 'date1' 
  and a <=  'date2
```

Python code below syntax I need help

```
with open('qry.sql', 'r') as sqlfile:
  sql_str = sqlfile.read()
  if (load_type == 'full'):
      sql_str = '*here i need logic to replace as mentioned above*'
  else:
      sql_str = sql_str
```

Comment: what do you exactly want sql command or python code

Comment: Require in python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `re` Regular Expressions.
`sep` will help you to split the string.

```
import re
sep = 'where'
load_type = 'full'
with open('qry.sql', 'r') as sqlfile:
    sql_str = sqlfile.read()
    if (load_type == 'full'):
        sql_str = sql_str.split(sep, 1)[0]
    else:
        sql_str = sql_str
print(sql_str)
```

Hope this will work :)

Comment: Thank very much... Can you explain me a little bit

Comment: In python, Regular Expressions will look for a particular pattern in a given string. I used sep = 'where' to look for the particular word and separate it from the string. as per your requirement, in the case of full, we don't require after the where class. So I used 'where' as the separator.